# Formatting Protobuf messages including non-ASCII strings

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

When a protobuf message contains a string with non-ASCII characters, `message.toString()` returns something like

```
alarm {
  message: "\320\227\320\260\320\262\320\265\321\200\321\210\320\265\320\275\320\270\320\265 \321\201\320\262\321\217\320\267\320\270 \321\201 mzta1."
}
```

I'd prefer to see the string including Cyrillic characters in logs. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: frankly, to get most of the benefits of protobuf, you'd ideally be using the *binary* format, not the *text* format. If you're using the text format, you could just as well use json etc.

Comment: @MarcGravell That's just for logging, I am of course using binary format on the wire :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 2.5.0, there is [`TextFormat.printToUnicodeString`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat#printToUnicodeString%28com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder%29).

Comment: it's deprecated so use 
TextFormat.printer().escapingNonAscii(false).printToString(messageHere);

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found -- copy a part of com.google.protobuf.TextFormat and removing string escaping in printFieldValue() method.

Answer (score 1):

There is method SetUseUtf8StringEscaping in class TextFormat::Printer:

```
// Set true to output UTF-8 instead of ASCII.  The only difference
// is that bytes >= 0x80 in string fields will not be escaped,
// because they are assumed to be part of UTF-8 multi-byte
// sequences.
void SetUseUtf8StringEscaping(bool as_utf8)
```

Comment: `Printer` is private in the Java library.